# count de 2 tablas en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas en mysql una es de cliente, otra de tienda y la de reserva, esta se relaciona con la tabla cliente y le roba el id y con la tbl tienda y también le roba su id, mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer un listado de todos los clientes y saber cuantas reservas tiene?, ya que puede tener muchas o ninguna, e intentado con un count y solo me toma en cuenta los que han reservado, y deseo que me tome en cuenta todos, y los que no realizaron ninguna en todo caso darme el count 0, como podria controlar eso?

**tabla cliente**

1. id_cliente nombre
2. telefono
3. ciudad
4. direccion

**tabla tienda**

1. id_tienda
2. nro
3. costo
4. dimension

**tabla reserva**

1. id_reserva
2. fecha_inicio
3. fecha_fin
4. condicion
5. id_cliente
6. id_tienda

He probado esta query:

```
SELECT c.Id_cliente, c.Nombre, COUNT(r.Id_reserva) as total
FROM cliente c 
LEFT JOIN reserva r 
ON c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente
GROUP BY c.Id_cliente
```

Me funciona sin embargo, me olvide de un detalle, en la tabla reserva, tengo un campo de condicion que puede ser 1 o 0, es 1 cuando estan vigentes y 0 cuando terminan, al realizar un where para que solo me tome en cuenta las reservas vigentes ya no funciona mi query.

Comment: Agrega el query esto se debe solucionar con un group by

Comment: Qué quieres decir con "Ya no funciona"? Con datos de ejemplo sería más fácil entender qué es lo que no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes implementar una junta de las dos tablas, definiendo que mantenga siempre el total de registros de una de ellas

**Usando LEFT JOIN**

*Todos los registros de la tabla a la izquierda y solo los registros que coincidan de la tabla derecha.*

```
SELECT id_cliente, nombre, COUNT(*) AS cantidadReservas
FROM cliente  
LEFT JOIN reserva USING(id_cliente)
GROUP BY id_cliente
```

**Usando RIGHT JOIN**

*Todos los registros de la tabla a la derecha y solo los registros que* coincidan de la tabla izquierda.

```
SELECT id_cliente, nombre, COUNT(*) AS cantidadReservas
FROM reserva  
RIGHT JOIN cliente USING(id_cliente)
GROUP BY id_cliente
```

Ten en cuenta que he usado `USING(campo_en_comun)` puesto que las tablas que se juntan tienen un campo que se llama igual y es exactamente tu principio de comparación por tanto hubieses bien podido usar la condición `cliente.id_cliente=reserva.id_cliente`, pero en casos particulares como estos la primera resulta mucho mas practica.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es la siguiente:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente, 
       c.nombre, 
       ISNULL(COUNT(1),0) AS cantidadReservas
       FROM cliente c 
       LEFT JOIN reserva r
           ON c.id_cliente = r.id_cliente
           AND r.condicion = 1
       GROUP BY
           c.id_cliente, 
           c.nombre
```

Sino usando una menos elegante y menos óptima subconsulta:

```
SELECT id_cliente, 
           nombre, 
           (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(1),0) 
                   FROM reserva r
                   WHERE c.id_cliente = r.id_cliente
                         AND r.condicion = 1
           ) AS cantidadReservas
           FROM cliente c
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con left join y righ join cuando solo haces un join este te devuelve los campos que están relacionados si usas un left join como su nombre lo indica tráeme los campos de mi tabla izquierda sin importar que si alguna vez a tenido un campo en común en este caso serian las reservas

Answer (score 0):

Deberia ser esta la instruccion cuando le aplicas la condicion where para obtener las reservas vigentes (condicion = 1), [ver ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/700006/2)

```
SELECT c.Id_cliente, c.Nombre, COUNT(r.Id_reserva) as total 
  FROM cliente c LEFT JOIN reserva r 
    ON c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente 
    where r.condicion = 1
    GROUP BY c.Id_cliente 
union
   (select id_cliente, nombre, 0
       from cliente where id_cliente
             not in ( select id_cliente from reserva
                             where condicion = 1  ) );
```

El segundo select obtiene los clientes sin las reservas vigentes.

Comment: lo he probado pero me repite los clientes

Comment: @Fernando,, podes colocar tu consulta sql ?

Comment: ya la actualize la pregunta

Comment: no comprendo el select, despues de union, me arroja error en el from

Comment: El select luego de la union hace que rellene los clientes que no tengan la condicion 1 ( clientes diferentes a tu primer select, para rellenar con valor cero)

Comment: Esta instruccion te funcion @fernando    select id_cliente, nombre, 0
       from cliente where id_cliente
          not in ( select id_cliente from reserva
                             where condicion = 1